# How to redefine framework constant in specific app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

I am developing an Objective-C SDK that is distributed in two parts, a bundle containing views and a statically compiled library. This SDK communicates to a REST API which has two deployments, development and production.

**Note :** When I say "pointing to develop" I mean the SDK is communicating with the development REST API, and when I say "pointing to prod" I mean the SDK is communicating with the production REST API.

I currently have a constants file called `NetworkConstants.h` which contains :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// development REST API
#define API_BASE_URL @"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port"
#else
// production REST API
#define API_BASE_URL @"http://api.company.com"
#endif

#define ROUTE_A API_BASE_URL @"/route_a"
#define ROUTE_B API_BASE_URL @"/route_b"
...
```

I then use `ROUTE_...` where needed.

This SDK is currently in a workspace containing the SDK project, a **very** simple test application, and a demo app developed by a company that has agreed to test our product (I say demo app because we use it to demo the product).

### The Goal

I would like to be able to push the apps to members of the team (through iTune Connect) and have the test app always pointing to develop and the demo app pointing to prod (though pointing to develop when I am developing).

### The Problem

When I archive and submit the project to iTune Connect the project is compiled in Release, and thus `DEBUG` is not set and the SDK points to prod. I created a custom build target and build script that compiles the SDK in Debug (and thus `DEBUG` should be set). I then added this build target as `Target Dependancy` in the test app's `Build Phases` and added the framework produced by build target to the test apps `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

This ^ did not work. It appears the SDK project is being compiled with `DEBUG` not set even though I am referencing the framework produced by the custom build script and this script builds with `-configuration Debug` :(

Any and all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to go into the `Edit Scheme` menu for the test app and set the project to archive in `Debug` rather than `Release`.